# Pull data from view with azure mobile apps offline data sycn

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Service as a backend in my Xamarin Andoid App. I want pull data from SQL View not a Table. How to pull data from VIEW, that is possible.?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, what you want is possible. You can try to define a custom API controller in C# to query the view from Azure SQL Database to render JSON body, then pull data from the custom api on Xamarin Android App.

Please refer to the offical documents as below.

1. The section [`How to: Define a custom API controller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#how-to-define-a-custom-api-controller) of the tutorial `Work with the .NET backend server SDK for Azure Mobile Apps`
2. The section [`Work with a custom API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#a-namecustomapiawork-with-a-custom-api) of the tutorial `How to use the managed client for Azure Mobile Apps`

Answer (score 0):

It's actually relatively easy to pull from an SQL View.  Check out Chapter 3 of my book at http://aka.ms/zumobook - this goes into detail on how to set up the view.  Once the view is defined properly (and matches the model in your code in the backend), it "just works".